# Does Ubuntu One's CouchDB still work?

Tags: ubuntu-one, application-development

I heard that Canonical was about to drop CouchDB from Ubuntu One, but there still few applications which relies on that:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/ThirdPartyProjects

I tried the [Stipple](https://launchpad.net/stipple), but looks like not replicating.

So, I'm wondering if that's still works as described in the following code tutorial:
[make your application sync with Ubuntu One](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2009/12/code-tutorial-make-your-application-sync-with-ubuntu-one/)

i.e. syncing every 10 minutes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not use desktopcouch for your application. If you want structured data storage in your application, you should start looking at using [u1db](http://people.canonical.com/~aquarius/u1db-docs/) instead.